# Finding the Windows version of a remote machine in the same network

Tags: windows

How do I find the version of another Windows machine in the local network?

Comment: related: [How can I determine the OS of a remote computer?](http://superuser.com/q/323238/241386)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Josh King noted you can use `srvinfo` which is a [**Windows 2003 Resource Kit**](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657) tool.

On Windows 7 you can use `systeminfo`

```
systeminfo /s remote_computer_name
```

Comment: Thanks for that, was trying to find a non server alternative but my Google wasn't strong enough!

Answer (score 7):

To get just the hostname and OS from systeminfo pipe in findstr, this eliminates the other noise

```
systeminfo /s [machine name]|findstr /i "host OS "
```

Answer (score 2):

[`nmap`](http://nmap.org/download.html) can perform [remote OS detection](http://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html).

It's not 100% accurate, but you'll have to see for yourself.

Here is an example result. I specifically picked a result that wasn't 100% accurate, but this machine **is** a Windows Server 2008.

> Warning: OSScan results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open and 1 closed port
>   Device type: general purpose
>   Running (JUST GUESSING): Microsoft Windows Vista|2008|7 (98%)
>   Aggressive OS guesses: Microsoft Windows Vista SP0 or SP1, Server 2008 SP1, or Windows 7 (98%), Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (98%), Microsoft Windows 7 Professional (97%), Microsoft Windows Vista Business SP1 (93%), Microsoft Windows Vista Home Premium SP1 (93%), Microsoft Windows Server 2008 SP2 (91%), Microsoft Windows Vista Home Premium SP1, Windows 7, or Server 2008 (91%), Microsoft Windows 7 (90%)
>   No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).

Answer (score 2):

Thank you [squillman] :)

While you have so many machines to be inspected, just do this:

(1) Create TXT file contains all hostnames of your machines. Eg: ALL-MACHINES.TXT

```
machine_number_0001
machine_number_0002
machine_number_0013
machine_number_0101
machine_number_0111
```

(2) Do FOR instruction within CMD:

```
C:\Users\MrCMD> FOR /F %S IN ('TYPE ALL-MACHINES.TXT') DO SYSTEMINFO /S %S [enter]
```

(3) Any comments for improvement are welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to one of the Windows Server resource kits (2003 for sure, not sure about newer versions) you can use the Srvinfo command.

```
Srvinfo \\remote_compute_rname
```

You'll get a host of information from it, but what you're interest in is:

> Product Name: Microsoft Windows XP Product Options: Professional

Comment: Thanks. Works for localhost but not for the other machines possibly because I'm not the admin in the network. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @shane If you are not an admin, there is no program that will give you that info.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here that need to do many machines and want to use PowerShell:

> Single Machine:
>   Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName ***Machine Name*** | Select-Object  CSName, Caption, BuildNumber, OSArchitecture
>
> All Machines:
>   Get-ADComputer -filter * | Foreach-Object {Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object  CSName, Caption, BuildNumber, OSArchitecture} | Format-Table -Property * -AutoSize

Assuming of course you have WinRM enabled.  You can batch enable WinRM via PS too but that's another topic.