# Determining the Windows 10 Versions in a Windows Domain

Tags: windows-10, remote, windows-domain, windows-server

is there a way to remotely retrieve the client's Windows 10 Version(eg 1709, 1809 etc.) in a Windows Domain?

Comment: [Cross-site dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330187/how-to-find-the-windows-version-from-the-powershell-command-line). Choose whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks @CaldeiraG but that looks like it's meant for local usage. My Question is in regards to retrieving that info remotely.

Comment: What about this? https://superuser.com/questions/312120/finding-the-windows-version-of-a-remote-machine-in-the-same-network